# Get same column in same row two times in SQL query

Tags: mysql

i have two tables **agreement** and **contact**,
**contact table** contains data about different type of contacts like 'Tenants','Landlord','Worker' etc.
and **agreement table** contains data about agreement like date,deposits etc.
[image]

Now i want to show agreement fields and cFirstName of both contacts in one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the contact table twice using aliases.

```
SELECT agreement.*, a.cFirstName, b.cFirstName
FROM agreement
JOIN contact a ON a.Contactid = agreement.LandlordID
JOIN contact b ON b.Contactid = agreement.TenantID
```

Comment: last line you did a mistake JOIN contact b ON b.Contactid = agreement.TenantID

Comment: That's the problem with cutting & pasting - often forget to check all changes made. Now fixed.